# Cyclic numbers of the form $2^n + 1$

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, finite-groups, heuristics

A cyclic number (or cyclic order) is a number $m$ such that the only group of order $m$ is the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$. The set of cyclic numbers admits a couple of cute number-theoretic characterizations, e.g. as the set of numbers $m$ such that $\gcd(m,\varphi(m)) = 1$.

> **Question.** Are there infinitely many cyclic numbers of the form $2^n + 1$?

I encountered this question while studying distance notions between the multiplication tables of certain finite groups: I find it quite captivating by itself, but a positive answer would also serve to simplify an otherwise gnarly argument in my current research.

Unfortunately, I don't know nearly enough number theory to even imagine how such problems could be attacked. My preliminary numerical investigation hints that cyclic numbers of this form should appear quite frequently, at least initially.

I can't expect a straight negative answer (it would imply that there are only finitely many Fermat primes), and while I'd be overjoyed to see a straight positive one, I'd also be more than content with number-theoretic heuristics illustrating the un/likelihood of infinitely many cyclic numbers in the given form.

Comment: Cyclic numbers are squarefree, and as far as I can tell, it is an open question as to whether there are infinitely many squarefree numbers of the form $2^n+1$.